# What is the difference between ./gradlew and run in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

In SpringBoot application, what is the difference between 
type `./gradlew` and execute main method in **App.java?

I'm in chaos. I thought `execute main method` contains `./gradlew` task. But it seems like doesn't contains that.

Because the result was different when I execute both task.

Comment: Gradle is a build tool... that it may also run your springboot application depends on the script defined in its build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

the w in gradlew is for wrapper as stated in gradle official website: 
    The recommended way to execute any Gradle build is with the help of the Gradle Wrapper (in short just “Wrapper”). The Wrapper is a script that invokes a declared version of Gradle, downloading it beforehand if necessary. As a result, developers can get up and running with a Gradle project quickly without having to follow manual installation processes saving your company time and money.